# convergence of sequences $(1, 1/2, 2^{1-n}, 0, 0, …)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's have sequence of sequences in $l_2$ space:

$$
{x_1}=(1, 0, 0, …)\\
{x_2}=(1, \frac 12, 0, 0, …)\\
{x_3}=(1, \frac 12, \frac 14, 0, 0, …)\\
…\\
{x_n}=(1, \frac 12, \frac 14, …, 2^{1-n}, 0, 0, …)$$

where norm is defined as
$||x||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2}$

I need to find convergation of this sequence when $n \to \infty $

Comment: $\sum_{x\in\left\{\left|2^{-(k-1)}-2^{-(k-1)}\right| : k\leq n\right\}\cup\left\{\left|2^{-(k-1)}\right|:k>n\right\}}x^2=...$ then factorize $2^{-n}$ and shift indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in each of your sequences, the $i$th entry changes exactly once. After that it is constant in all later sequences. This makes the limit easy to figure out. Now all you have to do is show that the sequences converge to it.

Answer (score 0):

The way the sequence is defined now, since you say that the sequence is in $\mathbb R^n$, is

$$x_n = (1,\frac12, \frac14, \dots, 2^{1-n})$$

There are no more zeroes after the final element, and your definition does not tell us what $x_{n+1}$ is. Therefore, your question cannot be answered (it is not clearly defined).

Comment: I think it is clear that he meant $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: @Math1000 It wasn't clear to me, since he used $n$, the same variable as  the one in $x_n$. Also, if he meant that, then I guess he should tell us so himself. And even then, he needs to define the norm of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: My mistake, it should be $l_2$ space. Speaking about norm, it is defined as square root of squares of elements.

Comment: @mathm Don't write that simply in this comment. Edit your original question.